# Declaring an array of character pointers (arg passing)

Tags: c

This is something that should be easy to answer, but is more difficult for me to find a particular right answer on Google or in K&R. I could totally be overlooking this, too, and if so please set me straight!

The pertinent code is below:

```
int main(){
    char tokens[100][100];
    char *str = "This is my string";
    tokenize(str, tokens);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        printf("%s is a token\n", tokens[i]);
    }
}
void tokenize(char *str, char tokens[][]){
    int i,j; //and other such declarations
    //do stuff with string and tokens, putting
    //chars into the token array like so:
    tokens[i][j] = <A CHAR>
}
```

So I realize that I can't have `char tokens[][]` in my tokenize function, but if I put in `char **tokens` instead, I get a compiler warning. Also, when I try to put a char into my char array with `tokens[i][j] = <A CHAR>`, I segfault.

Where am I going wrong? (And in how many ways... and how can I fix it?)

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is <A CHAR>?  Is it just a generic character?

Comment: @Daniel, that won't help - he has a two-dimensional array, not an array of pointers.

Comment: @John - yes, I wasn't sure how else to say that :) I have a lot going on in the function, but it's not too important to my question!

Comment: @Carl, does it matter?  Whether he has a 2d array or an array of pointers, isn't the expression the same?

Comment: @John, no, a 2-dimensional array is an array of arrays, not an array of pointers.  The memory layout is different.  The segfault in the OP's post is because of that.

Comment: @Carl so it does, just tested.  Guess I've been working with just pointers so long I forgot they were different.

Comment: @Carl, I see that the memory layout is different, but I seem to remember that one could also declare a 100x100 2d array by (1) first allocating an array of 100 pointers, and then (2) allocating 100 blocks of 100 locations and setting the pointers to point to the start of each of those locations. So, at the expense of storing the extra 100 pointers, you could reach tokens[i][j] more efficiently than if you had just declared tokens[100][100] as the OP did (you substitute an indirection for a multiplication). But that might not apply here or solve his problem. ;)

Comment: @Daniel, yeah it's a big gotcha sometimes.  I usually go the pointer method as well, makes life easier sometimes.

Comment: @John, yeah, that's what I have in my answer below.  I don't think there's necessarily a big efficiency difference.  But you do need to be consistent with your variables and the functions you pass them to as arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to specify the size of the second dimension of the array:

```
#define SIZE 100
void tokenize(char *str, char tokens[][SIZE]);
```

This way, the compiler knows that when you say `tokens[2][5]` that it needs to do something like:

1. Find the address of `tokens`
2. Move 2 * `SIZE` bytes past the start
3. Move 5 more bytes past *that* address
4. ???
5. Profit!

As it stands, without the second dimension specified, if you said `tokens[2][5]` how would it know where to go?

Comment: Haha, appreciate the final notes: I should have been more explicit and careful there: I do have i, j declared and do have tokens spelled correctly, and the str is an example I effed up: editing my post now. Thanks!

Comment: When you say SIZE, are you saying I should tell the function how long the second array is to be (100 in my example) or tell the function what the data-type's size is going to be? (sizeof(char) in my example)

Comment: @Isaac: Sorry, `SIZE` as I was using it was meant as in `#define SIZE 100`.

Comment: Ah, so of course, when I declare `tokens` it gives me 100*100 bytes (assuming a char is a byte on the system) in a row. So if I declared char *tokens[100] it would gives me 100 * (sizeof(char*)) bytes in a row. Splendid. Makes total sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're close.  Arrays and pointers aren't the same thing, even though it sometimes seems like they are.  You can either make your two-dimensional array out of pointers:

```
 char **tokens = malloc(100 * sizeof(char *));
 for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     tokens[i] = malloc(100);
```

And then use:

```
void tokenize(char *str, char **tokens)
```

or you can specify the size of the array in your `tokenize()` function:

```
void tokenize(char *str, char tokens[][100])
```